# Flagging logic on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to build a logic on PostgreSQL to flag some of the credit lines as 'renewals'. 
Each row represents either a new credit line, renewal case or just a change in terms (amount or the interests, which I don't show in the table for simplicity), which is not treated as renewed credit line. 
The rule for flagging the credit line as renewal is that it was approved at least 80 days after the original credit line granted date or 80 days after previous renewal case.
Column 'flag' shows what I would like to achieve. '1' represents new credit line or renewal, '0' represents other cases. I want to use flags, to distinguish which credit lines should be used for reporting (the ones marked 0 should not be reported).
What would be the best way to do it in PostgreSQL.

```
+----------+-----------+-----------------------+--------+------+------+
| customer |   date    | days_after_first_line | amount | rank | flag |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------+--------+------+------+
| a        | 1/1/2015  |                     0 |    100 |    1 |    1 |
| a        | 2/28/2015 |                    58 |    150 |    2 |    0 |
| a        | 3/26/2015 |                    84 |    150 |    3 |    1 |
| a        | 4/6/2015  |                    95 |    170 |    4 |    0 |
| a        | 6/11/2015 |                   161 |    170 |    5 |    0 |
| a        | 6/17/2015 |                   167 |    200 |    6 |    1 |
| a        | 7/14/2015 |                   194 |    200 |    7 |    0 |
| a        | 9/14/2015 |                   256 |    200 |    8 |    1 |
| a        | 9/14/2015 |                   256 |    200 |    8 |    1 |
| a        | 10/5/2015 |                   277 |    200 |    9 |    0 |
| b        | 1/1/2014  |                     0 |     50 |    1 |    1 |
| b        | 3/2/2014  |                    60 |     50 |    2 |    0 |
| b        | 4/1/2014  |                    90 |     50 |    3 |    1 |
| b        | 6/15/2014 |                   165 |     80 |    4 |    0 |
| b        | 7/20/2014 |                   200 |     80 |    5 |    1 |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------+--------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(customer, date, days_after_first_line, amount, rank, flag, 
                 new_flag, last_daysafter)
AS(
  SELECT customer, date, days_after_first_line, amount, rank, flag, 
         1 as new_flag,  days_after_first_line As  last_daysafter
  FROM table1
  WHERE days_after_first_line = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.customer, t1.date, t1.days_after_first_line, t1.amount, t1.rank, t1.flag,
         CASE WHEN t1.days_after_first_line - t.last_daysafter >=80
              THEN 1 ELSE 0
         END As flag, 
         CASE WHEN t1.days_after_first_line - t.last_daysafter >=80
              THEN t1.days_after_first_line ELSE t.last_daysafter
         END As flag
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN t ON t1.customer = t.customer AND t.rank + 1 = t1.rank
)
SELECT * FROM t
order by 1,2;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bb5eb/6

In this demo (in the result of this query) `flag` column is taken from data, and `new_flag` column is calculated, so you can compare expected results with actual (calculated) `new_flag` values.